# how to make instagram analysis web app

Tags: python, web-applications, data-analysis

I'm making a web app for Instagram analytics, it's for my portfolio. I've read the whole Instagram developers documentation, but I don't know where to start.

**Do you have an idea on where to start to make a web application for analytics?**

I want to make a simple dashboard with analytical data from Instagram such as gender, followers, location, keywords in bio.

I know a few programming languages by basics such as HTML, CSS, Python and R. But I have a few questions on where I should begin.

- Is there a framework for dashboard web apps?
- How much data can I get from Instagram? (want to focus specifically on Instagram)
- How can I establish the data in the backend?
- What tutorials are there to learn web apps and API(Instagram API)?

I'm looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! These broad questions typically aren't allowed here, but if you simply do a google search for your exact bullet points in your question - you'll get LOADS of great ideas. Try one of them - and if you get hung up on something more specific - come back and show us what you tried, and maybe we can help you a bit more. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a typical stackoverflow question but since you apparently just want a place to begin with, Codecademy have a free three hours course on Watson API to gather data from twitters users.

https://www.codecademy.com/

I guess it's close enough and might help you. Good luck.

Comment: Please do not encourage proscribed question types by giving answers to them.  I've done it myself, and since repented for my transgressions.  :-)

Comment: I'm sorry for the question, I now understand that Stackoverflow is more for coding issues. I'm gonna ask my question elsewhere, thanks for the help btw. The API course is useful